# How to add headers in Guzzle http

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, guzzle

I'm building a small application in `Laravel 5.5` where I'm using `Guzzle Http` to get call the api url and get the response, Few of the api calls have certain condition to have headers which works as authorization of the request generated. I'm trying to place the header something like this:

```
public function post(Request $request)
{
    try {
        if ($request->url_method == 'get') {
            $request = $this->client->get($request->url, [ 'headers' => [ 'access_token' => $request->headers->access_token]]);
        }
        else if ($request->url_method == 'post')
        {  $request = $this->client->post($request->url, [$request->request_data]);  }
        else { return response()->json(['data' => 'Invalid Method'],500);   }

        $response = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($request->getBody());
        return response()->json(['data' => json_decode($response->d)], $request->getStatusCode());
    }
    catch (ClientException $e) {
        return response()->json(['data' => 'Invalid Request.'], $request->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

But this is giving me errors:

> Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag::$access_token

Please checkout the screenshot:

[image: Guzzle HTTP client error]

Also when calling through the browser in console it gives me the same error:

[image: Browser console error]

Help me out in this, Thanks.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 26):

try this code

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;
..
..
..
$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'AccessToken' => 'key',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer token',
];

$client = new GuzzleClient([
    'headers' => $headers
]);

$body = '{
    "key1" : '.$value1.',
    "key2" : '.$value2.',
}';

$r = $client->request('POST', 'http://example.com/api/postCall', [
    'body' => $body
]);
$response = $r->getBody()->getContents();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add bearer in all small cases before access token like following -

```
$access_token = 'bearer '.$request->headers->access_token
```

Comment: User is not asking about bearer token (not asking for `Laravel/Passport` Auth headers).

Comment: @NitishKumar This solution adds header to the request where Webinions solution adds header to the client.